# windows 8 cygwin error " can not find compiler cl.exe in PATH "

Tags: windows, visual-c++, cuda, cygwin

I have visual studio 2013 and with that i can run my cuda file. but with cygwin it gives me above error. how to change environmental variable ?

$nvcc kernal.cu

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Easisest method is to find `VCVARSALL.BAT` file which comes with preconfigured targets such as x64. Then, if possible execute the file on cygwin or change the contents to cygwin-friendly format.

Basicly information you are looking for is in `VCVARSALL.BAT`